# Is there any danger to mixing wood types when repairing structural joists?

Tags: structural, lumber

I need to replace a 2 in. x 8 in. x 12 ft. joist and the only kind my hardware store has is "#2 Prime Kiln Dried Southern Yellow Pine Lumber".  I do not know if this is the same type of lumber as the existing beam that it will be attached to.  Is there any reason that the lumber has to be of the same kind?

Comment: It would probably be very helpful to those who _do_ know (and there are a number who frequent here who do), if you were to indicate what this is going to be supporting. Also, usually a single 2x8" is usually referred to as a "joist" or "rafter". I think it needs to be a bit wider than 2" before most folk call it a "beam". ;)

Comment: SYP (Sometime seen as Southern Yellow Hard Pine) is a cut above SPF, strength-wise.

Comment: Each wood will have its rated strength for bending and shear, it is tricky when you mix two different species of wood without knowing what you are putting together. Don't do it until you have the full knowledge of their structural properties.

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan, corrected it to "joist"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you need to “replace” your joist , but you also say you wonder if it’s ok to “attach” a different species together.

I’ll assume you are attaching joists together.

There are a couple of issues: 1) structural, 2) visual (aesthetics), 3) finishing

1. Structural each species is rated and graded. Seldom are joists sized to their ultimate stress grade, so I doubt over stressing your new joists (compared to the existing joists) is a problem. According to my little chart (Western Woods Use Book) Yellow Pine falls in about the middle of all lumber species, with Douglas Fir at the top (it’s available on the west coast) and Cedars and Hemlock near the bottom (structurally). Structurally, grades are about 50% more from top to bottom.
2. Appearance may be a bigger issue. If the joists will be visible after your repair, having bone joist that has large grain, large knots, etc. adjacent to another that has tight grain and tight knot will certainly be noticeable. “Hand” selecting the new joist can greatly reduce this issue.
3. Finishing (staining) the new joist will be the trickiest of all. All species accept stains differently. Be sure to test in a non conspicuous location before starting. (I’d recommend trying a “pre-stain” before starting. It makes everything more uniform.)

Note: There are no acids, etc. that could react from species to species to worry about. In fact glu-lam beam manufacturers will use pine on the inner plys and fir on the outter plys to save money on large glu-lam beams.

If my assumption regarding single joist vs. sistering an adjacent joist is incorrect, please advise. The new single joist will need to meet or exceed the existing joist stresses or there could be sagging, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I will clarify.  I'm replacing structural (non visible) joists in the floor of my second story.  It takes 2 12' joists to span my entire house and they overlap by about 3' and are currently fixed together with 2 large nails.  They do rest on a wall beneath so each joist is spanning from a structural wall to another structural wall.  My main concern would be differing expansion rates (due to temperature or moisture?) or something else that would cause structural weakness by using two different types of wood together.

Comment: There is no issue with using two different species of wood for structural repair.

Comment: Thanks @Lee!  That's answers my question